# Not able execute protractor conf.js command

Tags: npm

[image]
Can you please tell me why I am getting below error while trying to run the command **protractor conf.js**, please find below npm, node and protractor version. 
conf.js file there in the F:\Protractor directory.

------------ version details -------------------------------------------------

```
F:\Protractor>protractor --version
Version 5.3.2

F:\Protractor>npm -v
5.6.0

F:\Protractor>node -v
v8.11.3
```

----------------------- error------------------------------------------

```
F:\Protractor>protractor conf.js
[21:36:13] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[21:36:13] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js
[21:36:13] E/configParser - Error: Cannot find module 'F:\Protractor\conf.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:135:26)
    at Object.initFn [as init] (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js:93:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js:225:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

Comment: does C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./conf.js go any better? Or even protractor ./conf.js ?

Comment: Please use Markdown formatting to actually show the image: `![like this][url]` **NOT** `[like this][bad url]`.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far to resolve this?

Comment: I got the issue , actually I didn't  create .js properly , that why I facing that issue . . thanks for the response.

Comment: @ShivanandaRai I am facing the exact same issue. I have a file in the directory but it is failing with "Cannot find module....". What did you do to fix this?